# Google Cloud Functions: required/exported functions throw "handler is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

This works:

```
// index.js
module.exports = {
  getItems: (req, res) => res.send("Hello, World!")
};
```

testing with `functions call getItems` yields `Result: Hello, World!`

This does not work

```
// getItems.js
exports.getItems = (req, res) => res.send("Hello, World!");

// index.js
let getItems = require('./getItems');

module.exports = {
  getItems
};
```

testing with `functions call getItems` yields `Error: TypeError: handler is not a function
    at app.use.err (/Users...`

What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from `require()` is an object with *all* the exported things in the required file (not just the one you exported).

So, try this instead:

```
// index.js
let functions = require('./getItems');

module.exports = {
  functions.getItems
};
```

Comment: Haha wow thanks - just so used to using import and export default... I ended up just using `let { getItems } = require('./getItems');` and `module.exports = { getItems };` so I didn't have to create an unnecessary functions variable.